# Integrate playframework 1.x with elasticsearch 2.x

Tags: elasticsearch, playframework, lucene, playframework-1.x, elasticsearch-2.0

Our site is still working with play framework 1.4.2 and elasticsearch 1.5.2.
After upgrading our elastic to 2.3.4, I edited the play `dependencies.yml` file with the new versions of elastic (2.3.4) and Lucene (5.5.0), `run play "dependencies --sync"`, fixed the java code errors to use the new elastic classes and `play run`. Site went up but when trying to reach `localhost:9000` I get

> The localhost page isn’t working localhost didn’t send any data.
>   ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

What could be the cause?

Comment: show the more complete log, man

Comment: There is nothing in log. nothing is printed when I refresh the page. Last line stay as it was:"play ~ Listening for HTTP on port 9000 (Waiting a first request to start) ...". Today I even tried creating a new project ("HelloWorld" as in https://playframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/firstapp). Then I just added elastic dependencies:

Comment: Then I just added elastic dependencies:
require:
    - play
    - org.elasticsearch -> elasticsearch 2.3.4
And I got same error.
If I replace 2.3.4 with 1.5.2 its working.
Seems that play 1.4.x is not working with elastcsearch 2.x

Comment: Hi, issue was with netty version: play 1.2.4 is working with old version netty 3.2.5.Final, so when changing elastic to 2.3.4 and lucene to 5.5.0, the 'play dependencies –sync' command changed netty to 3.10.5.Final. Then, when I opened PlayHandler I saw that it didn't compile with it, so I needed to work on play 1.2.4 source code to work with netty  3.10.5.Final. (It was not easy!)